# Auto-Advance to Next Row While Exporting MySQL Data to CSV in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

I'm trying to get a script to work wherein certain selected records (depending on user input) are selected and then exported to a CSV file. I've tried all sorts of methods to do this; thus far this is the most successful I could find (actually from some code I did a few years ago), but it only returns the first row over and over again until the rows run out (you can see my sawdust-in-the-transmission method I used to tell PHP to keep getting rows until the result is exhausted). My questions: There is probably an easier way to do this-- any thoughts? If not, what can I do to get MySQL to advance to the next row the next time the loop is run? I thought it was supposed to do that anyway with mysql_fetch_array.

And yes, I've looked at fputcsv, but I can't seem to get any data to pass. The CSV file always comes up blank when I try to pass an array using fputcsv and getting the array via mysql_fetch_array, mysql_fetch_assoc, or mysql_fetch_row.

I've been learning as I go, and this is one of those times when I just haven't learned something in order to keep moving forward. And I don't know that much, either.

My code, or at least as much as is necessary:

```
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM student_history WHERE username='$username'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Query to show fields from table failed!:" .mysql_error());
    }
    $write = fopen("exportedmagic.csv", 'w') or die ("Can't create/open file to write! Drats!");
    fwrite($write, "ID, Username, Class, Status, Date, Time\n");
    while($numrows > 0) {
        $query = "SELECT id, username, class, status, date, time FROM student_history WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $id = $row['id'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $class = $row['class'];
        $status = $row['status'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $time = $row['time'];
        fwrite($write, $id .", " .$username .", " .$class .", " .$status .", " .$date .", " .$time ."\n");
        $numrows--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to-

```
if($numrows > 0) {
    $query = "SELECT id, username, class, status, date, time FROM student_history WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $class = $row['class'];
        $status = $row['status'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $time = $row['time'];
        fwrite($write, $id .", " .$username .", " .$class .", " .$status .", " .$date .", " .$time ."\n");
    }
}
```

With using `while($numrows > 0){$query= ... $numrows--;` you are redoing the query every time you go through the loop.

Also, instead of using `fwrite()` you can use [`fputcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) which makes it possible to add the row without needing to iterate through each column value in your current code.

Note: you will want to look at updating to either `mysqli_*` or `PDO` as the `mysql_*` extension is depreciated.

Comment: Excellent. I can't believe I didn't notice that the query was within the loop!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered MySQL's built-in feature to dump query results to a CSV output file?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html

It has a couple of caveats, such as the file is written on the database server.

But speaking of your code, I note that you put the mysql_query() *inside* the while loop, so it effectively starts the query over again after fetching just one row.  I'd expect something more like this:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  fputcsv($filehandle, $row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_` is deprecated. Please use http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php.

Here is PHP PDO example:

```
$stmt = $this->db
    ->prepare("SELECT 1;", [\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false]);
$stmt->execute();

$fp = fopen('compress.zlib:///foo.csv.gz', 'wb9');

while ($e = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $e);
}

fclose($fp);
```

If you wish not to use gzip compression, then simple remove the `compress.zlib://` prefix and replace `wb9` with `wb`.